# Flutter 2 - firebase_remote_config 0.6.0 & firebase_core ^0.7.0 version conflict

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-dependencies

As per [FlutterFire](https://firebase.flutter.dev/) Documentation, I have updated my flutter project to Flutter 2.

I have converted my project to **flutter channel beta** and dependency updated as below:

[image] [image]

Unfortunately, I am getting the following error:

> Because firebase_remote_config 0.6.0 depends on firebase_core ^0.7.0
> and no versions of firebase_remote_config match >0.6.0 <0.7.0,
> firebase_remote_config ^0.6.0 requires firebase_core ^0.7.0. So,
> because mars_remedies depends on both firebase_core ^1.0.0 and
> firebase_remote_config ^0.6.0, version solving failed. pub get failed
> (1; So, because mars_remedies depends on both firebase_core ^1.0.0 and
> firebase_remote_config ^0.6.0, version solving failed.)

Note: I have also tried to use **flutter channel dev** but I am getting the same error.

#### Another Error [Updated]:

> Because flutter_local_notifications_platform_interface 2.0.0+1 depends
> on plugin_platform_interface ^1.0.2 and no versions of
> flutter_local_notifications_platform_interface match >2.0.0+1 <3.0.0,
> flutter_local_notifications_platform_interface ^2.0.0+1 requires
> plugin_platform_interface ^1.0.2. So, because mars_remedies depends on
> both flutter_local_notifications_platform_interface ^2.0.0+1 and
> plugin_platform_interface ^2.0.0, version solving failed. pub get
> failed (1; So, because mars_remedies depends on both
> flutter_local_notifications_platform_interface ^2.0.0+1 and
> plugin_platform_interface ^2.0.0, version solving failed.)

My **pubspec.yaml** is:

```
  # For Location Information (Getting Location Details on Login or Register)
  geolocator: ^7.0.1
  geolocator_platform_interface: ^2.0.0

  flutter_local_notifications: ^4.0.1+1
  flutter_local_notifications_platform_interface: ^2.0.0+1
  plugin_platform_interface: ^2.0.0
```

All the above dependencies are conflicting with each other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `firebase_remote_config: ^0.9.0-dev.0` instead of `firebase_remote_config: ^0.6.0`.

> This version is not null-safe but has been created to allow
> compatibility with other null-safe FlutterFire packages such as
> firebase_core.

https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_remote_config/versions/0.9.0-dev.0

If it's still the same, try using `firebase_core: ^1.0.0`.

Answer (score 2):

use `dependency_overrides` in case of package conflict.

```
dependency_overrides:
  firebase_core: 1.1.0
```

And to know more about how to flutter resolve package version, and why there is conflict in packages, and how to resolve them, follow the below link:

https://medium.com/cashify-engineering/flutter-dependencies-resolution-2faecdbfce03

Answer (score 0):

As I have done some **try & catch**, I got the solution by using **dependency_overrides**

I have posted here : [Flutter version solving failed error - after Flutter 2 upgrade](https://pratikbutani.medium.com/flutter-2-upgrade-flutter-version-solving-failed-error-33ac1087cb6b)

```
dependency_overrides:
  firebase_auth: ">=1.0.0"
  firebase_core: ">=0.7.0"
  firebase_messaging: ">=8.0.0-dev.14"
  firebase_remote_config: ">=0.6.0"
  firebase_auth_web: ">=0.2.0"
  firebase: ">=7.0.0"
  flutter_local_notifications: ">=4.0.0"
```

It is just an example. You can use dependency as per your needs.

Answer (score -1):

remove the versions behind messaging and core, it works :

firebase_messaging:

firebase_core: